# How to fix a bad case rattle

Tags: case, noise

I have a full sized ATX case with several fans, including one on the door/removable side.  This fan makes the "door" rattle or vibrate loudly when the fan runs at full speed, such as at startup.  I can stop the rattle temporarily by placing my hand on the "door", or pushing an object next to it.

Do you have any suggestions for a permanent solution?

**Note:** The "door" in question is a slide out panel with two twist screws at the back to hold it in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old reliable: duct tape.  Ugly but cheap.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this a few times and there isn't really a good solution that works in every scenario.

The easy thing you can try is to tighten all the screws so that they do not vibrate, possibly bending the panel slightly near the fan (be **VERY** careful if trying this) or my favourite - replace the fan screws with noise cancelling / rubber screws.

[image]

Comment: These may not solve the problem if the rattle is between the two pieces of metal not the screw & the case cover--but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some sticky back foam strips and line the door with them around where it closes.

Something like this from [3M](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/3MAutomotive/Aftermarket/Products/Product-Catalog/?PC_7_RJH9U5230GE3E02LECFTDQCEK3_nid=9J788DSXR8beS07L5SX2K0gl)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Dynamat](http://www.dynamat.com).  I recalled their vibration dampening from car audio, and when I looked at their site, it looks like they've branched out into computer kits.